# Position fixed with margin and width 100% error

Tags: html, css, position

I have a simple div with `width:100%`and `position:fixed` to bottom. 
This is my CSS:

```
#footer {
     width: 100%;
     border: 1px solid #000000;
     position:fixed;
     bottom: 0;
     margin:0 5px;
}
```

When I apply margin left and right using the shorthand property, the footer is being pushed to the right which is very strange.

I created a fiddle for you to play with: [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3w6xE/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3w6xE/6/)**

```
#footer {
    width: calc(100% - 12px);
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    position:fixed;
    margin:0 5px;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

The 12px in the calc comes from the 5px of each margin, plus the 1px for the left and right border.

Or **option #2** (no `width` or `calc()` needed). Simply set the left and right to 5px and the footer will stretch the full width, minus those amounts:

```
#footer {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    position:fixed;
    left:5px;
    right:5px;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dqXw5/)**

Comment: Although looks good but i think it won't work with old browser and it seems like a hack...i want to know what actually causes this strange behaviour of ignoring margin with 100% width

Comment: @j08691 the point i was trying to make was there is default margin and padding with div and body tag and since he is giving "margin:0 5px;" the code will naturally set left margin which results in the div pushing to right to see that he just had to set margin to 0px correct me if i am wrong i think question was why the footer is pushed right

Comment: @user3127499 - The OP *wants* a 5px left and right margin on his footer -- he's not unclear of why there's a space, he wants a margin and for the footer to take up the full width.

Comment: aha...the second solution is THAT'S IT!! No need for 100% width...thanks very much (Y)

Comment: I personally don't like the `calc()` method (personal preference?!). But I like your second suggestion! Upvoted!

Answer (score 3):

I would do two things:

- Set `box-sizing: border-box`. This will ensure paddings dont affect the outer width of your element.
- Set margin and padding to 0 for html and body elements as these have applied a margin by default in most browsers.

You can now set the element padding instead of trying a workaround with the margin values.

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    position:fixed;
    padding:0 5px;
}
```

Can be tested in this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qY3Lp/)**

Comment: This seems like a hack for me...do you know why width 100% and margin have this strange behaviour?

Comment: 100% width will, as it says, set the width to 100% of the parent element. If you apply a margin as well, the margin will be added on top of these 100% - causing problems as in your example. The above is not a hack, it's simply modifying the box model, setting the outer width to the elements borders, which are outside the margins. This will solve the margin problem. Read more about the [CSS Box Model](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/) and [Box-sizing fix](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).

Comment: but why the margin is pushed to right?? It should add margin to both right and left making the edges of both border not appearing...why specifically it pushes to the right side?

Comment: Because the default text align is to the left. When the total outer width (width + margin + border) will exceed 100%, the element will stick to the left side, and it will extend to the right.

Comment: this is what the point i was trying to make @Anders G is spot on

Comment: I'll have to correct my two previous comments. The border-box includes width and _padding_, not _margin_. Sorry. This should not affect the CSS in my answer though :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use bottom: 0; In my code below I also used padding rather than margin, padding will affect the 'margins' within the div where as margin refers to the outside.

`#footer {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/3w6xE/3/

Comment: I want the padding not the margin. Also, it looks exactly the same I did. Still pushed to right :)

Comment: You need to set the body to have a margin: 0; - beyond that, the margin on your #footer is pushing it to the right. http://jsfiddle.net/3w6xE/12/

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), (which I think is a good solution, despite the [limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/calc)), you could wrap the element:

```
<div class="footer_wrapper">
    <div class="footer">test</div>
</div>
```

The parent, wrapper element is fixed with a width of `100%`, and the child `.footer` element has the margin. As others have mentioned, use [`box-sizing:border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) in order to include the border in the element's width calculations. Support for `box-sizing` can be seen [here](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing).

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/zLa5D/)

```
.footer_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
}
.footer_wrapper > .footer {
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:0 5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

As an alternative to using a margin, you could also just add `left:5px`/`right:5px`.

---

If you want the reason behind why your example was behaving as it was, it's simply because a fixed element's position is relative to the viewport. The element therefore has a width of `100%`, of the window thus explaining why the `margin` wasn't behaving as expected. Usage of `calc()` allows you to subtract the margin from the width.

Comment: Doesn't box-sizing have limited support as well?

Comment: @MichaelSamuel It's [supported in IE8 and up](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing).

Comment: It has better support than calc(). And it's in my opinion more logic as it's specifically meant for these cases.